# How do I discover the shorthands defined by babel in my language?

Tags: babel, xy-pic, shorthands

The reason I want to do it is that I want to set brazilian language in babel and I want to use xy-pic package, but I have to use it inside an environment in which the shorthands are off.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE (minimum working example)? It would make it a lot easier to understand your question.

Comment: The shorthands are described in the documentation of babel.

Comment: Try Portuguese portuges, portuguese, brazilian, brazil. As Ulrike mentioned from a console type `texdoc babel` for the manual.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer at the time of this writing (Babel 3.18) this is incorrect. You have to read separate manual to get the list of shorthands (e.g. for Russian it's `texdoc babel-russian`).

Answer (score 8):

The shorthand defined for Portuguese (of Portugal and of Brazil) all use the `"` character and it's this character to watch for.

---

Let's see a list for some of the languages supported by Babel.

## Languages with no shorthand

- Croatian, English (any variety), Indonesian, Hebrew, Interlingua, Irish, Lower Sorbian, Malaysian, North Sami, Romanian, Scottish, Welsh

## Languages with only `"` as defined shorthand character

- Albanian
- Bulgarian
- Danish
- Dutch
- Finnish
- German (old and new orthography, also Austrian)
- Icelandic
- Italian
- Norwegian
- Polish
- Portuguese (also Brazilian)
- Russian
- Serbian (with Latin script)
- Slovene
- Swedish
- Ukrainian
- Upper Sorbian

## Languages with other shorthand characters

### Basque

- `"`
- `'`
- `~`

### Breton

- `:`
- `;`
- `?`
- `!`

### Catalan

- `"`
- `'`
- `` ` ``

(Note: `'` and `` ` `` can be deactivated at loading time.)

### Czech

- `"`
- `-`

### Esperanto

- `^`

### Estonian

- `"`
- `~`

### French (all varieties)

- `:`
- `;`
- `?`
- `!`

### Galician

- `"`
- `.`
- `'`
- `~`
- `<`
- `>`

### Greek

- `~`

### Hungarian

- `` ` ``

### Kurmanji

- `^`

### Latin

- `"`
- `^`
- `=`

### Slovak

- `"`
- `^`
- `'`
- `-`

### Spanish

- `"`
- `.`
- `<`
- `>`
- `'`

(Note: some of them can be activated or deactivated with options at load time.)

### Turkish

- `:`
- `!`
- `=`

## Final note

In many cases it's quite safe to turn off some or all of the shorthands, if direct UTF-8 input can substitute them.

Comment: Why can't we disable all shorthands by just saying `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}`...`\end{otherlanguage}` when necessary?

Comment: @AlexG No. The shorthands do nothing, but the shorthand characters remain active.

Comment: Nice table. May I copy it in the babel docs? Babel 3.9 will provide a package option to set which shorthands do you want to activate (now in beta: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/babel-beta).

Comment: @JavierBezos Of course you can! I'm confident it's accurate, but you might doublecheck it.