# babel: adding language shorthands to work inside glossaries

Tags: glossaries, babel, shorthands

I added ngerman shorthands to my english babel as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngerman-s-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-lan). But they do not work for glossaries, and probably in other macors as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/babel-shorthand-doesnt-work-in-macros). I load all the acronyms as a separate file in the preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\makeatletter
\initiate@active@char{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{english}\bbl@activate{"}}
\addto\noextrasenglish{\bbl@deactivate{"}}
\declare@shorthand{english}{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries  
\newacronym{CP-OFDM}{CP"~OFDM}{Cyclic Prefix OFDM}

\begin{document}   
CP"~OFDM \\
\acs{CP-OFDM}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve the problem for acronyms? One solution is to move them inside the main text, after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Babel shorthands are enabled only after `\begin{document}`. Just say `\AtBeginDocument{\input{file}}` instead of `\input{file}` (where `file.tex` contains the acronym definitions).

Comment: If the only language is `english`, you can use "user shorthands" with `\useshorthands{"}` and `\defineshorthand{"~}{...}`, which is much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other questions in the site that cover similar problems

- [Should I place \title, \author, \date in the preamble or after \begin{document}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument)
- [babel shorthand "| doesn't work in macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/babel-shorthand-doesnt-work-in-macros)

but this one raises a different problem.

As explained in the second linked question, shorthands are enabled only after `\begin{document}` and `babel` has good reasons to do this.

However, a long list of acronyms after `\begin{document}` would pollute the document and you're right when thinking that they are best placed in the preamble.

A solution might be

```
\shorthandon{"}
<list of acronyms>
\shorthandoff{"}
```

and the list can also be put in a file `myacronyms.tex` so that the above becomes

```
\shorthandon{"}
\input{myacronyms}
\shorthandoff{"}
```

However, there's a better solution for this setup:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\input{myacronyms}}
```

will load the file *after* the shorthands are enabled, while the instruction is still in the preamble.

If you use the `\shorthandon` way, enable all shorthand prefixes you need. Here you find a [list of shorthands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95868/4427) for the various languages.

Comment: If you use the `\AtBeginDocument` approach, you'll need to put it before you load `glossaries` to avoid the generation of the [`.glsdefs` file](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:techissues). (Otherwise the glossary/acronym definitions will occur after `\newglossaryentry` changes its behaviour.)