# xypic error at macro @!

Tags: errors, xy-pic

Here is an example of the problem I encounter with xypic

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@!{
P\ar[r]^{p_{2}}\ar[d]_{p_{1}}&Y\ar[d]^g\\
X\ar[r]^f&Z}
\]
\end{document}
```

And below is the error I got when I typeset

```
./essai.tex:16: Xy-pic error: <addop> or <direction> or one of    1RCMLHW*! expect
ed.
\xyerror@ ...#2}\fi \errmessage {Xy-pic error: #1}
                                              }
l.16     \xymatrix@!
                {
```

I strongly suspect it comes from babel and the french option messing up stuff, since the character ! does not seem to be recognized (@R works fine for instance). What can I do about that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving the problem for `!` is not sufficient, as also `?;:^="` are used in Xy-pic syntax.

You can globally solve it by disabling shorthands in all Xy-pic constructions:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\xy{\shorthandoff{!?;:^="}}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@!{
P\ar[r]^{p_{2}}\ar[d]_{p_{1}}&Y\ar[d]^g\\
X\ar[r]^f&Z}
\]
\end{document}
```

Without `etoolbox` it would be, instead of `\preto\xy{...}`,

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\xy}
\edef\xy{\noexpand\shorthandoff{!?;:^="}\the\toks0 }
```

Comment: Very useful answer ! After the one of David Carlisle, I was using the option \shorthandoff as a global option parameter of the babel package, but I think yours is more precise and allow fine tuning with less side effects. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tested it but unfortunately a construction like
    A_{\varphi^{-1}(q)} \ar@{}[r]^(.25){}="a"^(.75){}="b" \ar "a";"b"^{\varphi_{q}} & B_{q}
inside a xymatrix bracket does not seem to work anymore : the ; character does not seem to be handled well anymore ... Do you know what is happening ?

Comment: @brunoh Here's what I get from `\xymatrix{
  A_{\varphi^{-1}(q)} \ar@{}[r]^(.25){}="a"^(.75){}="b" \ar "a";"b"^{\varphi_{q}} & B_{q}
}
`:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/KTWQL.png

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my main file, I used `\preto\xy{\shorthandoff{!?;:}}`
before the declaration of the xy package. If I put it after, everything works fine ! Thank you again I will choose your answer as the preferred one but I also like the one of David Carlisle ...

Comment: @brunoh I get no such warning.

Comment: I forgot to delete the previous `\preto` instruction before the package's call. My bad. Sorry for the inconvenience, and I edited my previous comment.

Comment: I ran into similar problem with \usepackage[slovak]{babel}. Here I had to use `\shorthandoff*{^}`. The same is probably true with other languages [having ^ among shorthands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95860/how-do-i-discover-the-shorthands-defined-by-babel-in-my-language). Thanks to David Carlisle for his advice [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/conversation/babel-and-xypic-and-shorthand).

Comment: @Martin You're right, I added also `=` which is a shorthand in `babel-turkish`.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just solved a similar problem to that of @egreg with a construction like `\xymatrix{s\ar@/_3mm/[r]_{t}="t"&t}` it was originally more complicated but the problem is the quotation character, solved it by adding `\shorthandoff{"}`

Comment: @MetalMathician Added also `"`

Comment: I get errors such as `Package babel Error: I can't switch '^' on or off--not a shorthand.`for all characters except for `"`. Other people might have to find which characters are and aren't shorthands in their particular language. I am using the `spanish` option for `babel`.

Comment: Alright, a partial list of shorthands for different languages can be found in the documentation. See page 14. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel

Answer (score 6):

You can locally get `!` back with `\shorthandoff{!}` :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\shorthandoff{!}
\xymatrix@!{
P\ar[r]^{p_{2}}\ar[d]_{p_{1}}&Y\ar[d]^g\\
X\ar[r]^f&Z}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @David_Carlisle Clear & precise answer ! Very useful for me because I also learn the mechanism of getting rid of shorthands in babel locally or globally. Thank you very much.